# Two-way binding and a Selector

Tags: wpf, data-binding, two-way

Setup:

1. There is a ComboBox that is bound to a ObservableCollection.
2. There is a Car object in the UI. Its Color property is bound to the ComboBox's SelectedItem (the binding: `<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Car.Color}".../>`
3. The color list can change in the database and should be refreshed sometimes.

The problem:

When the `ObservableCollection<MyColor>` is refreshed (== this means that it sends a `Reset` inside its `CollectionChanged` event) the Car's Color property is set to the first item in the collection => the list is refreshed => ComboBox reloads the collection and sets its selected item to the first one in the collection => Car's color is changed to the same first item (because of the two-way binding) => problem

So in short - how can I avoid this? How can I tell on reload to take the selected item right away from the binding?

Comment: ObservableCollection<MyColor> - what is the code for MyColor class

Comment: It does not really matter. Just imagine a usual 'public class MyColor : INotifyPropertyChanged { /* some members */ }'. Nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the binding while the collection changes:

```
var binding = comboBox.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty).ParentBinding;
comboBox.ClearValue(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);

ChangingData.Clear();
// <Rebuild>

comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, binding);
```

Comment: I, personally, have a different case here, but your answer is quite good and maybe useful to some people. In my code though I had a specific case when I just refreshed the collection items themselves (instead of refreshing the whole collection). Anyway, thanks for the answer.